# Include a javascript class in a parent class, rather than in window when it is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, we are request `jQuery` with `<script src="`. From now on `window.jQuery` or `jQuery` will be available.

But I want to prevent it from being used in this way and collect it in a pool.

**For example:**

```js
container = {
   jQuery: (function(){}(), // jQuery' script,
   ..,
   ..,
   ..
};

container.jQuery('.hi').addClass('hello');
container.jQuery(document).on('click', function(){});
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: May I ask: why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery` is just a global variable and as such can be reassigned.

```js
var container = {};
container.jQuery = jQuery;
jQuery = $ = null;
console.log(container.jQuery("div").length);
// gives error $ is not a function:
$("div").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>a div</div>
```

`.noConflict()` allows you to reassign `$` back to what it was before jquery was loaded, so you may want to call that first before obliterating `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a module system *or* call `jQuery.noConflict(true)`. That will give you the jQuery to use as well as reset the globals: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/